# How do I access the keys and values of a dictionary read from a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I would like to test accessing the `keys` and `value`s of a `dictionary` that is read from a text file. The goal is just to test out accessing them now but later I will want to match the values against a `dataframe` column and create a new column with the `values` that match. below is code and error message and what the dictionary looks like in the text file.

```
with open('dict_test.txt') as f:
    variable=f.read()

variable

for n in variable:
    print(n, variable[n])
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\XXXXXX.py in <module>
      5 
      6 for n in variable:
----> 7     print(variable[n])
      8 
      9 # var2 = map(lambda x: x.replace("'", "").replace(",", "").strip(), variable)# understand map and strip

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

this is what the dictionary in the text file looks like:

```
{"Delay one": ["this delay happens often", "this delay happens sometimes"], "Delay two": ["this delay happens almost alot", "this delay happens almost never"], "Other": ["this delay happens sometimes"]}
```

Comment: You might want to use `ast.literal_val` to convert the string representation of the dict into a real dict. If it is actually json, you would need `json` module.

Comment: `f.read()` returns a plain string, so `variable` is just a string.  It looks like you might want to use `json.load()` instead.

Comment: There *is no dictionary in your file.* Your file contains *text*. You really should use a standard serialization format like JSON or pickle

Answer (score 0):

You are currently reading the file as just a string (basically plain text). You'll need to parse the text into an actual dictionary that you can later access and manipulate. There are a variety of ways to do this in Python, including the built-in `json` module using the json.load method.

Comment: No, the JSON module *will not parse* the string representation of python objects, not generally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Python dictionary even though it looks like it. Best thing to do is to save your txt file as json, and then deserialize it. I recommend reading about json serialization and deserialization. Here is the code that should work for you:

```
import json

#DESERIALIZING JSON
#load() - use this to load a JSON file into python
filename = 'filename.json'
with open(filename,'r') as read_file:
        to_python = json.load(read_file)
        print(to_python)
```